# RVIZ trace robot path

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a bagfile with tf transforms containing /body frames

Is it possible to trace the path of the body frame in RVIZ?

kind of like in this tutorial, but I want to see a line the turtle followed in RVIZ,rather than a line to the transform...
http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171771/rviz-trace-robot-path/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[hector_trajectory_server](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_trajectory_server) does what you request. See also this other older [Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/28069/how-to-visualize-a-frame-pose-as-a-path/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest thing to do is publish something to be rendered in rviz such as a Pose or Point at (0,0,0) in the /body frame and turn up the decay time.

If you want to do it in a way that is persistent and recordable the quickest thing to do will be to write a quick python node which records the points and then renders a Polygon path such as the planners and updates it each time the path is resampled.

All messages are in [geometry_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2